# Apache - Exclude local network to redirect HTTPS

Tags: linux, apache, shell, ubuntu, mod-rewrite

I have configured virtualhost as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```

I require to exclude redirecting HTTP to HTTPS request for my local network/subnet ie. (172.16.0.0/16)

I am using GCP HTTP loadbalancer.

Can somebody help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GCP launched http to https redirection at the load balancer so you don't need to configure rewrite rule on apache anymore, with this said, you can access backends either directly from your local Nerwork or you can separately have an internal http load balancer on http to access it from local network and external for external users.

Comment: Thanks James..  Can you share any document regarding http to https redirection on loadbalance, since I am not able to find that on console.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-http-https-redirect